Variance of an Itô Integral
Question
Using Itô Isometry and the fact that
$$\int_{0}^{t} Z_s \ ds = \int_{0}^{t} (t-s) \ dZ_s,$$
show that
$$Var \left(\int_{t}^{T} Z_s - Z_t ds \right) = \frac{(T-t)^3}{3}$$
where $Z_s, Z_t$ are standard Brownian motion.
My working
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{t}^{T} \left(Z_s - Z_t\right) \ ds & = \int_{t}^{T} Z_s \ ds - Z_t \int_{t}^{T} \ ds\\
& = \int_{0}^{T} Z_s \ ds - \int_{0}^{t} Z_s \ ds - Z_t(T-t)\\
& = \int_{0}^{T} (T-s) \ dZ_s - \int_{0}^{t} (t-s)\ dZ_s - Z_t(T-t)
\end{aligned}$$
Using Itô isometry and the fact that $Var(Z_t) = t,$
$$\begin{aligned}
Var\left(\int_{t}^{T} Z_s - Z_t \ ds\right) & = Var \left(\int_{0}^{T} (T-s)\ dZ_s - \int_{0}^{t} (t-s)\ dZ_s - Z_t(T-t) \right)\\
& = \frac{T^3}{3} + \frac{t^3}{3} + (T-t)^2 t,
\end{aligned}$$
which does not correspond with what I have to show.
I am unsure where I went wrong and any intuitive explanation will be highly appreciated!

The variance of
$$
\int_t^TZ_s-Z_t\ ds
$$
is
\begin{align}&\textstyle
\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_t^TZ_s-Z_t\ ds\right)\left(\int_t^TZ_u-Z_t\ du\right)\right]=\displaystyle\int_t^T\int_t^T\mathbb E\Big[(Z_s-Z_t)(Z_u-Z_t)\Big]\,ds\,du
\end{align}
This is easy to calculate

\begin{align}&=\int_t^T\int_t^T\Big(\mathbb E[Z_sZ_u]-\mathbb E[Z_tZ_u]-\mathbb E[Z_sZ_t]+\mathbb E[Z_t^2]\Big)\,ds\,du\\[2mm]&=\int_t^T\int_t^T\Big(\min(s,u)-t -t + t\Big)\,ds\,du\\[2mm]&=\textstyle\int_t^T\Big(\int_t^us\,ds+\int_u^Tu\,ds\Big)\,du-(T-t)^2\,t\\[2mm]&=\frac13(T-t)^2(T+2t)-(T-t)^2\,t=\frac{(T-t)^3}3\,.\end{align}

If someone insists to use Ito isometry:
\begin{align}
\int_t^TZ_s-Z_t\,ds&=\int_0^T(T-s)\,dZ_s-\int_0^t(t-s)\,dZ_s-(T-t)\,Z_t\\[2mm]
&=\int_0^T(T-s)\,dZ_s-\int_0^t(t-s)\,dZ_s-\int_0^t(T-t)\,dZ_s\\[2mm]
&=\int_0^T(T-s)\,dZ_s-\int_0^t(T-s)\,dZ_s\\[2mm]
&=\int_t^T(T-s)\,dZ_s\,.
\end{align}
This has variance
$$
\int_t^T(T-s)^2\,ds=\frac{(T-t)^3}{3}\,.
$$
